# Angular-Kendo window custom actions

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-window

I'm trying to create a window with a custom action using Angular-Kendo, and have reached a problem.

When using Kendo (minus angular) i would add functionality [like explained here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/actions):

```
window.data("kendoWindow").wrapper.find(".k-i-custom").click(function(e){
    alert("Custom action button clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, in Angular-Kendo, access to the window object is by `$scope.windowname` and is only available after the `kendo-window="windowname"` directive.

I am currently bypassing this by binding the actions at the `k-on-open` like...

```
    var firstLoad = true;

    this.onOpenCallback = function () {

        if (firstLoad) {
            $scope.messageBodyWindow.wrapper.find(".k-i-custom").click(function (e) {
                alert("OMG");
            });
            firstLoad = false;
        }
```

This solution, however, feels like a cheap hack. is there a "proper" way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to find the answer to this without success! Telerik are staying very quiet over the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the Angular-Kendo directive in a custom directive and put the desired functionality into the `link` function. This will register your custom binding once without any of this 'first time opening the window boolean' hackery.

```
  <div custom-kendo-window>
  </div>
```

The custom directive contains the kendo directive in its template...

```
.directive('customKendoWindow', function(){
  return {
    template: '<div kendo-window="win" k-title="\'Window\'" k-width="600" k-height="200" k-visible="false"> <div id="customAction" style="cursor: pointer;">custom click action</div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        $('#customAction').bind('click', function(){
          alert('Custom action fired!');
        })
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a [code pen](http://codepen.io/hally9k/pen/LpbVjK) showing the simple wrapper as shown above and then a configurable wrapper with the click binding being set up in the link functions of each of the directives.